# How do I change GTK theme of my app in run time?

Tags: application-development, python, themes, gtk, quickly

I recently noticed that monodevelop, can change GTK theme in runtime . How do I add it in my quickly app?

Comment: Please dont! A single theme for all apps is an important part of good usability. Individual apps should not change the theme themselfs.

Comment: @xubuntix: Thanks but I know that , but I  wanna let the user to chose favourate theme (Iff they wish) for my app(as in mono develop)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Gtk.CssProvidor` to load a css file. For example:

```
css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
css_provider.load_from_file("file_name.css")
screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
style_context = window.get_style_context()
style_context.add_provider_for_screen(screen, css_provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
```

Where "file_name.css" is the css file you want to load (the themes in ubuntu seem to be in /usr/share/themes/THEME_NAME/gtk-3.0/) and window is the window widget you are using. If you want to load css from a string you can use `css_provider.load_from_data(string_name.encode('UTF-8'))` instead of `css_provider.load_from_file("file_name.css")`

Resources:

- [GtkCssProvider Reference Page](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkStyleProvider.html) (I couldn't find the python one)
- [Styling Gtk With Css](http://gnomejournal.org/article/107/styling-gtk-with-css)

Comment: Registered just to upvote you sir!

Answer (score 2):

If you want, you can check out my [Blog Post on Python, GTK and CSS](http://wolfvollprecht.de/blog/gtk-python-and-css-are-an-awesome-combo/)

I tried to do a little write-up on how to do it (I used it for my quickly app as well).

Comment: Upvote because content in link is great!

Comment: It is not good to use an external link. These external links often disappear and then this becomes useless...